# Hello what should i do to make this diamond shape using python3

Tags: python-3.x

```
--*--
-***-
--*--
```

bars are blanks

```
print('', '*', ' \n', '***', ' \n', '', '*', '')
```

This is what i made and it doesn't work...I thought ''=blank and since there's comma it's one more blank so there should be 2 blanks as a result? 
anyway what should i do using only one print f(x)

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in as a single string:
`print(' * \n***\n * ')`
Output:

```
 * 
***
 *
```

You can do this, because Python treats `\n` as new line character and it will not interfere with the rest of the text, even if it "touches" it. Putting it in a single string makes it more readable. There is no reason to fragment the whole statement with commas, when you can do it all in one string.

Comment: why did i think that space bar won't work? thanks ' * \n***\n * ' doesn't it matter whether I put blank between \n and * or not?

Answer (score 0):

Basically:

`''` --> empty string

`' '` --> one space char (or blank)

So, modifying your print:

Only change the first argument from `''` to `' '`

```
print(' ', '*', ' \n', '***', ' \n', '', '*', '')
```

You can also simplify it passing only 1 argument:

```
print('  *  \n *** \n  *  ')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! now i get it

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to upvote and choose and accepted answer if it was useful.